# CSV result into math calc

Tags: python, csv

I can't get the result from a file into calc code as "s".

```
import csv
with open('csv/1.n03', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    for row in reader:
        row = "".join(row)  
        print(row)

s = 'row'
x = '0'
y = '1'
counter = s.count(x)
num0 = (''+ str(counter))
counter = s.count(y)
num1 = (''+ str(counter))
a = int(num0)
b = int(num1)
sum = (a+b)/b
print (sum)


0
0
0
0
0
1
0
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "2n04.py", line 21, in
>   
>       sum = (a+b)/b ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Comment: what u triing to achieve?; Here b is zero so you got the error

Comment: b is 1, if change  s = 'row' to  s = '0000011' i get sum 3,5 not ZeroDivisionError

Comment: No quotes `s = row`

Comment: s = row, not working

Comment: add csv snippet

Comment: 0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0  (a+b)/b = 10.5

Comment: when s = row ; what output do you get

Comment: ZeroDivisionError

Comment: add s value here

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: print s value and add here

Comment: s has non value at the moment need to get value from csv

Comment: `s = row;print('S value is', s)`

Comment: Did't work output 1 and 1.5

Comment: `s = row;print('S value is', s)` ; add s value only

Comment: output = S value is 1  and 1.0

Comment: Add image of csv ;

Comment: csv/1.n03: 21 rows 0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0 one digit on each row

Answer (score 0):

You need to join all rows

```
import csv
with open('csv/1.n03', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    s = "".join(row[0] for row in reader) 
print('S value is', s) 
a = s.count('0')
b = s.count('1')
if b:
    print((a+b)/b)
else:
    print('B is zero')
```

Comment: 21 rows,  B is zero

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2n04.py", line 4, in <module>
    s = "".join(cell for row in reader) 
  File "2n04.py", line 4, in <genexpr>
    s = "".join(cell for row in reader) 
NameError: name 'cell' is not defined

Comment: S value is 000000010000000000010
10.5
Thank you, you solved the probleme :-)